# PHP + mySQLi last id inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I know that mySQL has the query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

This works properly well when it's a small site and not many users uses it. But, when your website has more users making use of it, there could be a problem with this select, because I can insert something at the same time as another one, so that could generate  the problems.

I've been reading something from `mySQLi` Transactions, but I don't know much about it. Is this the only way to get the last id that I  have  inserted, not from other that can insert content at the same time as me??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it doesn't cause problems.  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is connection-specific, and each PHP script execution has a different MySQL client connection so users are isolated from one another when using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: "_The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own._" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: in php, you can use `$id = mysqli_last_insert_id()` right after your `mysqli_query('insert …');`. The id returned will be always the one corresponding to your actual script

Comment: Transactions serve a different useful purpose - you may execute multiple `INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE` queries and if any one of them fails or you encounter another condition for which they should not be committed to the database, you can roll them all back inside a transaction, restoring your database to its previous state.

Comment: Thanks for your backup guys! Now I understand it better, as said, once they told me that, so that's why I asked here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be a problem, because `last_insert_id()` will get you only the last id inserted in the same session. You don't have to worry.

And as a note, it's just `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`, not `...FROM table`, you don't want to execute this function for every row in the table.

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Comment: Thanks for that. Was a time without programming so may I have to refresh somethings (they told me that once, from the last_insert_id problem could generate).

Thanks again, you and all of you guys!